# If I was to take light and loop it between two iron cores, like a transformer with copper; what would happen?

Tags: spacetime, experimental-physics, time-travel

Precursor: I am not a physicist, and don’t claim to be. I’m sorry if the question is easily answered.

Question: If I were to take light and loop it between two iron cores, similar to the way copper in a transformer is wound between two iron cores and a connecting core on top to give more or less voltage; would something happen? Like if I took 5 loops of light around one iron core, and then had 30 loops of light around another iron core; and connected them with a top piece of iron, would something happen? I ask because if I can take 480v and step it down to 120v through iron and a less wound piece of copper, then why can’t I change the pressure and space of light with the same method of stepping up and down it’s amount of energy? This is an honest question, and I’m sorry if I’m just uneducated and sound like a nut for some reasons I wouldn’t understand. Thank you to anyone with the insight and the time to answer this question.

Comment: Forestalling other questioners: this could be set up using a fiber optic cable.   But of course the rules about interaction of photons with magnetic fields, not to mention the orientation of AC electric fields (transformers don't work with DC electricity in the wiring) will lead to the answers.

Comment: Thank you! Once you said the law of interaction between photons and magnetic fields, I looked it up and realized the answer to my question! I guess this is a silly question then. I have another one though. I wonder if you could use inverters and rectifiers to intermittently change between A/C and D/C to solve the transformer issue? Like a motor for a fan unit has a kill switch which is D/C, however the motor is also connected to a VFD (variable frequency drive) to minimize wear and tear and requires the inverter and rectifier in order to work with the VFD’s A/C and the kill switches D/C.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing would happen. You would need a fiber optic cable, no light gets out, the iron core does nothing to the light, so your second fiber optic (with more or less loops) would not have any light in it or any connection with the other light.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I should’ve done more research on photons and magnetic field relationships before asking the question. I keep coming up with ideas in my head to only get shot down by the common laws of physics. It’s disappointing but not discouraging.